# Como guardar registros en base de datos a través de DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework

Como puedo iniciar un bloque de código donde indique guardar los registros actualizados después de hacer modificaciones directamente en un grid.

desde un botón "Guardar" indicar la instrucción.

El SaveChanges(); no me guarda los cambios realizados.

```
private void dgvProductos_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                this.dgvProductos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
                this.rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
                this.dgvProductos.CurrentCell = this.dgvProductos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1];
                this.contextMenuStrip1.Show(this.dgvProductos, e.Location);
                contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position);
            }
        }


        private void contextMenuStrip1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProductosEF _bdVentas = new ProductosEF();

            if (MessageBox.Show("¿Desea eliminar permanente el producto?", "¡Advertencia!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                if (!this.dgvProductos.Rows[this.rowIndex].IsNewRow)
                {
                    this.dgvProductos.Rows.RemoveAt(this.rowIndex);
                }
            }

            _bdVentas.SaveChanges();

        }
```

Comment: _bdVentas no tiene nada, si lo acabas de instanciar, que esperas que guarde? ya tenes varias preguntas sobre temas similares, me parece que vas a tener que sentarte y revisar tu sistema y sobre todo leer la documentacion de EF, porque lo que tenes son errores de concepto. EF tiene los objetos en memoria, y no puede ser que vos los instancies cuando los necesitas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private void contextMenuStrip1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //al hacer eso, declaras un nuevo contexto
        //Debes usar el contexto que esta asociada la grilla. 
        //es por eso que no guarda nada
        //ProductosEF _bdVentas = new ProductosEF();

        if (MessageBox.Show("¿Desea eliminar permanente el producto?", "¡Advertencia!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            if (!this.dgvProductos.Rows[this.rowIndex].IsNewRow)
            {
                this.dgvProductos.Rows.RemoveAt(this.rowIndex);
            }
        }
        _contactoAsociadoAlaGrilla.SaveChanges();
        //_bdVentas.SaveChanges();

    }
```